# ignore everything except a folder in bower

Tags: javascript, bower, gitignore, glob

Is there a way to ignore everything except for a folder and it's contents for a bower library. I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
"ignore": [
  "./!(dist)"
]
```

My folder structure looks like this and I only want to distribute the `dist` folder.

```
/dist
  myLibrary.js
  myLibrary.min.js
/src
  ...
/node_modules
  ...
package.json
bower.json
...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use the following ignore patterns:

```
"ignore": [
    "*",
    "!dist/",
    "!dist/*"
]
```

Notice you need the first pattern in order to first ignore everything.

Comment: This also works `"ignore": ["*", "!dist/*"]` (the first `!dist/` is unnecessary)

Comment: is it possible to ignore the distribution folder and have the contents alone, so that on bower install I dont get the dist folder but directly get the contents inside it?